# How to make a ui-select field as required?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to make the following field (settings) in my form as a required field in. How can I do it?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-5 control-label"> Settings*</label>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <ui-select multiple tagging="adPreferredEmailDomainPatternTransform" id="emailDomainPatternListInput"
                   tagging-tokens="SPACE|," theme="bootstrap"
                   ng-disabled="settings.enableAuthentication == 'false'"
                   ng-model="settings.emailDomainPatternList">
            <ui-select-match>{{$item.displayFormat}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in emailDomainPatterns">
                {{item.displayFormat}}
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `required` attribute

Comment: I tried adding `<ui-select required>...</ui-select>`. but it didn't work

Comment: @fatCop, request you the change the accepted answer to the one that provides a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this is a known and long-standing bug. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/258) for more information.

Comment: is it still not fixed in ui-select?

Answer (score 15):

None of the answers really worked for me. I solved it using a simple hidden input with the same ng-model as the ui-select and validating that in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="email_domain_pattern" ng-model="settings.emailDomainPatternList" required/>
```

Comment: This is the best workaround, simple yet effective for me!

Comment: An example would have helped

Comment: @SaeedJassani, I have added the code snippet to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: [_Constraint validation: If an `<input>` element’s `type` attribute is in the Hidden state, it is barred from constraint validation._](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#hidden-state-typehidden)

Comment: @c24w, ok. i wasn't aware of this and it used to work when I wrote this answer. Can you try adding some style to hide it? Eg make the opacity:0 or visibility/display:hidden/none.

Comment: @NiravGandhi, I tried with `visibility` and `display`, but neither worked.  I guess the browser still doesn't know where to show the validation errors.  I've decided to abandon `ui-select` for my current need because it's so damn flaky.

Comment: Update for the record: `opacity: 0` _does_ work, so you could position the invisible input so the validation error appears to be in the correct place.

Answer (score 9):

You can write ng-required="true".

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-5 control-label"> Settings*</label>

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <ui-select multiple tagging="adPreferredEmailDomainPatternTransform"                 
                   id="emailDomainPatternListInput"
                   tagging-tokens="SPACE|," 
                   theme="bootstrap"
                   ng-disabled="settings.enableAuthentication == 'false'"
                   ng-model="settings.emailDomainPatternList"
                   ng-required="true">
            <ui-select-match>{{$item.displayFormat}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in emailDomainPatterns">
                {{item.displayFormat}}
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes doesn't work for me either...it might be because of the ui-select version, I am looking into this now too..

Comment: this http://plnkr.co/edit/RN9Fry?p=preview worked for me at last, as long as you are sure that your elements are in a div that uses ng-form="myForm". I have searched for this for a long time, try it @Ashutosh.

Comment: it only works for single select fields not for multiple.

Answer (score 3):

you can use custom directive.

```
angular.module("app").directive('uiSelectRequired', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.uiSelectRequired = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (attr.uiSelectRequired) {
                    var isRequired = scope.$eval(attr.uiSelectRequired)
                    if (isRequired == false)
                        return true;
                }
                var determineVal;
                if (angular.isArray(modelValue)) {
                    determineVal = modelValue;
                } else if (angular.isArray(viewValue)) {
                    determineVal = viewValue;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                return determineVal.length > 0;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set required first.

```
<form name="form">
  <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.premise.$touched && form.premise.$invalid }">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="label-color">PREMISE <span class="red"><strong>*</strong></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <ui-select name="premise" 
                 id="premise" 
                 ng-required="true" 
                 ng-model="selectedPremise" theme="select2" 
                 ng-disabled="plantregistration.disabled" 
                 class="max-width" title="Choose a premise">
        <ui-select-match 
             placeholder="Select or search a premise...">
             {{$select.selected.name}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices 
          repeat="person in plantregistration.list12 | filter: {name: $select.search}">
          <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
      <span ng-show="form.premise.$touched && form.premise.$invalid" 
            class="label-color validation-message">
            Premise is required</span>
    </div>          
  </div>
</form>
```

Add some scss (or convert to css) like;

```
.label-color {
        color: gray;
    }
.has-error {
    .label-color {
            color: red;
        }
        .select2-choice.ui-select-match.select2-default {
            border-color: red;
        }
    }
.validation-message {
        font-size: 0.875em;
    }
.max-width {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-5 control-label"> Settings</label><span class="text-danger"><strong>*</strong></span>

<div class="col-xs-7">
    <ui-select ng-required="true" multiple tagging="adPreferredEmailDomainPatternTransform" id="emailDomainPatternListInput"
               tagging-tokens="SPACE|," theme="bootstrap"
               ng-disabled="settings.enableAuthentication == 'false'"
               ng-model="settings.emailDomainPatternList">
        <ui-select-match>{{$item.displayFormat}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in emailDomainPatterns">
            {{item.displayFormat}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```