# how to handle ng disabled in submit button and required directive on ui select in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-disabled

I want to disable submit button when ui select element have null value or no option selected by ui select drop down list.

UI select code:

```
<form name="KeyConfigurationForm">
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <h3>
                Company App Configuration
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="ibox-content">
            <div class="row col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Company</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <ui-select ng-model="configvalues.CompanyInfoID" ng-change="getCompanyModulesListByCompanyID($select.selected.CompanyInfoID); GetFranchiseList($select.selected.CompanyInfoID)" theme="bootstrap" required>
                            <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="itm.CompanyInfoID as itm in Companies | selectFilter:{Name:$select.search, Code:$select.search}">
                                <div ng-bind-html="itm.Name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                <small ng-bind-html="itm.Code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
                    </div>
                </div>






            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveConfigurationKeys()" ng-disabled="KeyConfigurationForm.$invalid"> Save Configuration</button>
            <a href="index.html#/index/main" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

But in my view Save(submit) button is enabled even if nothing is selected in drop down list. All code is placed in a form div named as KeyConfigurationForm.

(edited) After assigning my form a name all required fields impacting correctly on submit button but the problem with ui select was that on selecting nothing in it, **returns null value** which was not handeled correctly.

Comment: Its my first question so please ignore minor errors :) and do correct me please

Comment: Can we see the form element?

Comment: if nothing is selected (or was de-selected), `configvalues.CompanyInfoID` will be null/undefined. Simply check if it's *falsy*: `ng-disabled="KeyConfigurationForm.$invalid && !configvalues.CompanyInfoID"`. Keep in mind that if you are sending some data to your backend, you need to validate it again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a ui-select field as required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141730/how-to-make-a-ui-select-field-as-required)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236836/1102310
It is a nice workaround.

Comment: Frank Modica I edited my code and now you can see my form element.

Comment: Aleksey Solovey, I tried this but it is not working. I am only getting data from backend and not sending data to backend. After loading page button is enabled but nothing is selected in ui drop down.

Comment: Groben I tried ng-required instead of required but same of no help.